# Fréchet derivative of scalarfield operator $ f \mapsto \nabla f \cdot \sigma $?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics, frechet-derivative

Let $\sigma \in \mathfrak{X}(\Omega)$ be a fixed smooth vector field on an open domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Consider the operator $T\colon C^\infty(\Omega) \to C^\infty(\Omega)$ on the space of smooth scalar fields $f\colon \Omega \to \mathbb R$ given by $Tf := \nabla f \cdot \sigma$. Is there a simple expression for the Fréchet derivative of $T$? (or perhaps some other sensible interpretation of the derivative of $T$).

Since $T$ is linear the basepoint of the derivative should not matter. I also have a suspicion that it might be given by pointwise mutliplication with $-\operatorname{div} \sigma$, but I am not sure. I am only concerned with the cases $\Omega \in \{\mathbb R^d, (0,1)^d\}$ for $d=2,3$, and I also do not care about regularity conditions, but I do not think it will be relevant.

Comment: Riesz Representation Theorem might be what you are looking for: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793137/representation-of-the-fr%c3%a9chet-derivative-of-f-e-n-where-fh%e2%86%92h-h-is-a-h

Comment: Can you write down the definition of the Frechet derivative? Since it is linear, the derivative is just itself (In my definition).

Comment: You are right! It was not until I began writing down the problem here that I included the idea of taking the Fréchet derivative, but with this definition it is obviously just itself ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "Is there a simple expression for the Fréchet derivative of ?"  What Banach space structure are you putting on $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$?  My impression is this issue may have contributed to your confusion.  $T$ does not seem to be defined on a Banach space in your question so asking about its Frechet derivative is jumping the gun a bit.

Comment: Yes it probably did, and I am still not sure that I am considering the right derivative. The application that I want to use it for is a complete mess with regards to mathematics and does not explain the math very rigorously. In my setting the scalar fields are actually images in $H^\infty (\Omega)$ or $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, and they are endowed with the regular $L^2$-norm. See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6854, in particular page 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a remark note that $Tf = \langle \nabla f , \sigma\rangle = df(\sigma) = \sigma(f)$ by unpacking definitions.

Concerning the Frechet derivative of $T$, note that $T$ is a continuous linear map and as such equal to its own derivative (remember that the derivative is the linear part of the best *affine* approximation of a map, hence the derivative of any continuous linear map must be this linear map itself).